# No encuentra la ruta en Laravel 8. 404 not found

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax, laravel-8

Tengo el siguiente problema:
**Tengo una formulario donde se supone que tengo una ruta de un video que quiero borrar** el formulario es el siguiente.

```
<form action="/deletevideo/{{ $video->id }}" name="form" method="DELETE">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{csrf_token()}}" name="_token" id="token">
  <a href="/editvideo/{{ $video->id }}" class="text-info">Edit</a> - 
  <a href="#" class="deletevideo text-danger" id="{{ $video->id }}">Delete</a>
</form>
```

**La ruta en el archivo web es la siguiente:**

```
Route::DELETE('/deletevideo/{id}', [VideosController::class, 'deleteVideo'])->name('deleteVideo');
```

**La llamada Ajax es la siguiente:**

```
function deleteVideo() {
    $('.deletevideo').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(!confirm("¿You are sure to delete the video?")) {
            return false;
        }
      
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var form = $(this).parents('form');
        var url = form.attr('action');
        var row = $(this).parents('tr');
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('#token').val();
        console.log(url);
        $.ajax({
            'url': url,
            type: 'DELETE',
            data: {
                _token: CSRF_TOKEN,
                'id': id,
            }, success: function(response) {
                row.fadeOut();
                $('#exito').css('display', 'block');
                $('#exito').html('<span>'+response.mensaje+'</span>');
      
            }, error: function(error) {
                $('#error').css('display', 'block');
                $('#error').html('<span>Something went wrong.</span>');
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Y lo peor es que tengo otra ruta para borrar otros datos igual y si que funciona.
El error que me da es un **404 not found**

Comment: @BetaM no, pero lo tengo asociado así @ section('jsprivado')
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('/js/videos/videos.js') }}">
@ endsection

Answer (score 2):

Para un formulario no existe un método `DELETE` (Ref: [HTML
Living Standard: Form submission attributes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-method)).

[Method Field](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#method-field)

> Dado que los formularios HTML no pueden realizar solicitudes `PUT`, `PATCH` o `DELETE`, deberá agregar un campo `_method` oculto para falsificar estos verbos HTTP.

Si bien no estás enviando directamente el form, sino que haces una llamada [jquery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), lo mismo aplica.

Entonces en el ajax el `type` debe ser `POST`. Y para que laravel lo interprete como `delete`, debes agregar a la data un atributo `_method` con valor `'delete'`.
Algo así:

```
var url = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');
var CSRF_TOKEN = $('#token').val();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        _token: CSRF_TOKEN, 
        _method: 'delete', 
    }, 
    success: function(response) {
        //...
    }, 
    error: function(error) {
        //...
    }
});
```

También, para rutas con nombre es preferible usar el helper `route` para generar la url completa que corresponde a la ruta que quieres acceder:

```
<form action="{{ route('deleteVideo', ['id' => $video->id]) }}">
```

Comment: Esta respuesta es genial, si no te molesta la editaria para agregarle enlaces de referencia

Comment: @BetaM, me había apoyado en tu respuesta para escribir ésta, ya que la tuya tenía referencias. Agregué una referencia a la documentación de laravel donde explica que el campo `_method` se usa para "falsificar" los verbos que soporta laravel.

Comment: Yo también incluiría esto https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-method y de mi *respuesta* decidí quitarla y que sea la tuya la que perdure.

Comment: @BetaM Genial, se me había perdido ese. Ahí lo agregué.

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

- Los únicos métodos que puedes declarar en el atributo `method` son `get` y `post` por tanto debe quedar así:

  ```
  method="POST"
  ```

  - De hecho *este pudiera ser tu mayor problema*, te recomiendo [leer mas sobre este detalle](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-method)
- Luego dentro de tu `form` debes declarar una directiva que ayude a identificar a `delete` de esta forma:

  ```
  @method('DELETE')
  ```
- El nombre del método *delete* va en minúsculas:

  ```
  Route::delete...........
  ```

**Opciones para el tema de la ruta**

1. Si ya tienes declarada una ruta nombrada, entonces en tu `form` puedes aprovechar el método `route` con una sintaxis de esta forma:

   ```
   <form action="{{ route('deleteVideo', ['id' => $video->id]) }}" method="POST">
   ```
2. O por otro lado, puedes probar quitando el atributo `action` de tu formulario y declarando la ruta directo dentro de tu AJAX de esta forma (**evitando realizar el paso anterior**):

   ```
   let url: `deletevideo/${id}`
   ```

   - Para este punto `id` será la variable que almacena el acceso a la etiqueta `a` que guarda el id del elemento a eliminar

Comment: Gracias por los consejos, pero en el trabajo el arquitecto nos dice de usarlo así DELETE incluso en en el formulario, y ya había intentado eso de las dos formas, había intentado hasta crear nuevas rutas y nuevos métodos para ver si llegaba aunque solo fuera para saludar con un "HOLA" y no iba al final he tenido que usar  los comandos para limpiar la caché y route.

Comment: El detalle es que si checas el enlace que te di al inicio de mi respuesta, explica lo que ocurre si el valor del method esta mal o no esta presente además que muestra los únicos válidos de uso

Comment: Sin contar que si el verbo de la petición no coincide con el esperado en Laravel (*en la declaración de la ruta*) entonces puede no procesar tu petición por que las rutas no coinciden.